# How to remember the toggle state of the sidebar in AdminLTE3?

Tags: adminlte

There is a lot of time i get this problem back, and cost me much time to find out the answer. So, i write here for me and some one need this solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Adminlte3.**

Just simple add data-enable-remember="true" to your "pushmenu" button. Example code:

```
<a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button" data-enable-remember="true"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Link ref:
https://adminlte.io/docs/3.0/javascript/push-menu.html